# How do i change the values in table B to be same as table A?

Tags: sql

There are two tables with the same field name 'Episode no'. The field in both the tables are Varchar but table A stores values as 1,2,3,4 and table B stores as 1.0, 2.0 3.0, 4.0. How would you join the tables?

Firstly changed the data type to numeric but how should i change the values in table B so that it is same as table A

Comment: You would join the tables on their related key, but with delimited data violating 1NF, a Varchar used where clearly it should be integer or numeric, the same value duplicated in multiple tables I'd question the validity of everything.

Comment: Why do you use `varchar` instead of an `integer`?

Comment: you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: This is a bit misleading. You don't store the strings `'1,2,3,4'` and `'1.0, 2.0 3.0, 4.0'`, but only `'1'` and `'1.0'` and `'2'` and `'2.0'` etc., correct? And you have changed the columns' data types to numeric already? Then you are done. `1` is the same numeric value as `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do an UPDATE with a JOIN to update the values in table B based on the values in table A. Something like:

```
UPDATE tableB AS b
JOIN tableA AS a ON b.'Episode no' = a.'Episode no'
SET b.'Episode no' = a.'Episode no';
```

Assuming you've already converted the data type of 'Episode no' in both tables to numeric.